# Which Server Distro?

Tags: linux, java, solaris

So I need to set up an application server with glassfish and I was wondering which one I should go with. Usually I hear that it's best to go with the one you're most comfortable with, but in this case since it's not a regular web server, would something like Solaris be a better fit or is there a specific linux distro I should use?

To Clarify, I'm looking for something easy to set up for Java Web Applications (Java EE) that would require minimal configuration to run.

Comment: You might consider narrowing the question a bit; it's pretty subjective.  From the SuperUser FAQ: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion."

Answer (score 1):

I've always had great luck with Ubuntu Server.  It's easy to install, easy to maintain, and Ubuntu's documentation is second to none.  A quick bit of Googling even returns a [tutorial for glassfish on Ubuntu](http://skytteren.blogspot.com/2009/05/installing-glassfish-v3-on-ubuntu.html).

Comment: 100% ack if you need easy maintainance ubuntu server is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I always believe in the use of the system you are most comfortable with.  I run a lot of CentOS / RHEL 5 and a quick search brought up [this](http://anandnalya.com/2009/04/07/running-glassfish-as-a-service-on-centos/) how to for glassfish.  That being said I am sure there are how tos out there for just about any OS and glassfish.
[Glassfish on CentOS](http://anandnalya.com/2009/04/07/running-glassfish-as-a-service-on-centos/)
[Glassfish on Solaris](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_guide_for_installation_Glassfish_on_Solaris)
[Glassfish on Windows](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/how-to-install-glassfish-on-windows/)

I would say that any of the [supported platforms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4494/abpak/index.html) are a good choice. ;)